# How to pass html email parameters to an asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, html, email, service, web

I need to pass html email parameters var1 and var2 into an asp.net page and run an asp.net web service from the asp.net page which will use the var1 and var2 gotten from the html email.
I will appreciate any help on this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your email could have a link like

```
<a href="yoursite/default.aspx?var1=value1&amp;var2=value2">text</a>
```

Then you can get this info on your `default.aspx` page with

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var var1 = Request.QueryString["var1"];
    var var2 = Request.QueryString["var2"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Linus this is the answer I was looking for.